# Problem Counting Items For an Individual Row

Tags: t-sql

I need to find the count for ActivityID and AdditionalActivityID for each DailyFieldRecordID based on when GroupID = 260 and ItemID is either 1302,1303,1305,1306. The problem I'm having is that regardless of how many rows for each individual DailyFieldRecordID there are, there can only be one ActivityID and one AdditionalActivityID regardless of how many rows comply with the constraints.
Say someone is filling out a form and they list what their Activity for the day was and also what other activity they might have. They can only list one primary activity(ActivityID) and one secondary activity(AdditionalActivity). But during those activities they could participate with multiple groups(GroupID) or people(ItemID). So when I'm running this query I'm able to separate the rows based on the constraints, but I only want to count how many activities they participated in, which will either be 1 or 2 for each DailyFieldRecordID, regardless of how many groups or people were involved. Right now my query is counting each ActivityID and AdditionalActivityID for each row that meets the criteria, which can give me many more than just 1 or 2 for each DailyFieldRecordID. I'm just not sure how I would go about doing this. Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

```
 DailyFieldRecordID:   GroupID:  ItemID:  ActivityID: AdittionalActivityID:
    3369320             260        1302      37                     0
    3369320             260        1305      37                     0
    3369320             210        2222      37                     0
    3369320             250        2222      37                     0
    3372806             260        1302      56                     56
    3372806             260        1305      56                     56
    3372806             250        2222      56                     56
    3388888             260        2222      45                     32

  Expected Result:
   DailyFieldRecordID:       Count:
        3369320                 1
        3372806                 2



 Current Result:
    DailyFieldRecordID:      Count:   
        3369320                2
        3372806                4
```

'

```
select a.DailyFieldRecordID,
        count(case when a.ActivityID <>0 then 1 else null end) +
        count(case when a.AdditionalActivityID <>0 then 1 else null end) as count
from AB953 a
where a.GroupID= 260 and exists(
        select b.DailyFieldRecordID
        from AB953 b
        where a.DailyFieldRecordID = b.DailyFieldRecordID and b.ItemID in (1302,1303,1305,1306))
group by DailyFieldRecordID
```

Answer (score 0):

I get this result when trying your data:

```
DailyfieldrecordID   Count
3369320                3
3372806                2
3388888                1


 SELECT DailyFieldRecordID,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ActivityID <>0 then 1 else 0 end  +
        CASE WHEN AdditionalActivityID <>0 then 1 else 0 end) as Count
from Foo
where GroupID= 260 and exists(
        select b.DailyFieldRecordID
        from fOO b
        where DailyFieldRecordID = b.DailyFieldRecordID and b.ItemID in (1302,1303,1305,1306))
group by DailyFieldRecordID
```

New query: you might need to fiddle with this, not sure if your data is wrong or not....... cant get it to select 3 and then 2:

```
SELECT DailyFieldRecordID,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN ActivityID <>0 then 1 else 0 end  +
        CASE WHEN AdditionalActivityID <>0 then 1 else 0 end) as Count
from Foo
where GroupID= 260 and DailyFieldRecordID IN(
        select b.DailyFieldRecordID
        from fOO b
        where b.ItemID IN(1302,1303,1305,1306))
group by DailyFieldRecordID
```

Comment: I used a separate count for each activity. I'm not sure how you got 3388888 to show in the count since its ItemID of 2222 is not in b.ItemID in(1302,1303,1305,1306)

Comment: There are 3 3369320, not sure why that should be 2

Comment: i added an alias to the first table and now it should calculate correctly. I still have an issue with only counting activities once though

Comment: I think its the count statement you are using. I used two separate ones for each activity then added them together.

Comment: This query would not give what is being asked. It is counting duplicates. Also, accessing the same table twice can be avoided. You can take a look at my solution below and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT  A.DailyFieldRecordID
            ,ActivityID             = IIF(A.ActivityID = 0, NULL, A.ActivityID)
            ,AdittionalActivityID   = IIF(A.AdittionalActivityID = 0, NULL, A.AdittionalActivityID)
    FROM    AB953 A
    WHERE   A.GroupID = 260
    AND     A.ItemID IN (1302,1303,1305,1306)
)
SELECT  DailyFieldRecordID
        ,CNT = COUNT(DISTINCT ActivityID) + COUNT(DISTINCT AdittionalActivityID)
FROM    CTE
GROUP   BY DailyFieldRecordID;
```

I created this DDL and test data for testing:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS AB953
GO

CREATE TABLE AB953 (
DailyFieldRecordID INT,  GroupID INT,  ItemID INT,  ActivityID INT, AdittionalActivityID INT)

INSERT INTO AB953
VALUES
 (    3369320,             260,        1302,      37,                     0   )
,(    3369320,             260,        1305,      37,                     0 )
,(    3369320,             210,        2222,      37,                     0 )
,(    3369320,             250,        2222,      37,                     0 )
,(    3372806,             260,        1302,      56,                     56    )
,(    3372806,             260,        1305,      56,                     56    )
,(    3372806,             250,        2222,      56,                     56    )
,(    3388888,             260,        2222,      45,                     32    )
GO
```